# using operator in having clause. ERROR

Tags: mysql, sql

```
set @mte := (select max(salary * months) from employee);

select count(name), salary*months
from employee
group by salary*months
having salary*months = @mte;
```

This compiles with the error

> ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 12: Unknown column 'salary' in 'having
>   clause'
>   P.S: Woud like to use having clause instead of where.  I'm learning through experimenting. Would like to know why this doesn't works
>   P.S: USING MYSQL LATEST

Comment: why would you add this condition In the `having` clause?, it should be in a `WHERE`

Comment: Does MySQL require an aggregate in the having clause?

Comment: learning by experimenting. Want to know where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using cross apply here and replace having with a where clause:

```
set @mte := (select max(salary * months) from employee);

select count(name), SalMonth
from employee cross apply (select salary*months SalMonth)a
where SalMonth = @mte
group by SalMonth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, what you are doing should be ok; HAVING should be able to operate on aggregate results and any fields grouped by (at least as they are grouped, in this case as `salary*months`). It seems as though MySQL is trying to recalculate that product from the individual field values (that it no longer has access to at that stage.)

Try aliasing `salary*months`, and using the alias in GROUP BY and HAVING.

...but as has been said in comments, that kind of condition should be done in the WHERE anyway; and can be done in a single query:

```
select count(name), salary*months AS some_product
from employee
WHERE salary*months = (select max(salary * months) from employee)
group by some_product;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution does not use a variable or subquery:

```
select count(name), salary*months as tot
from employee
group by salary*months
order by tot desc
limit 1;
```

You can also fix your version by using an alias:

```
select count(name), salary*months as tot
from employee
group by salary*months
having tot = @mte;
```

Or by using an aggregation function:

```
having max(salary*months) = @mte;
```

I think you might have found a parsing bug in MySQL.  Your version *should* work, but apparently the expression is being decomposed into the column references -- and MySQL thinks they need to be aggregated.